# Sum 2 columns and sort it with DESC and only showing 1 records only with prioritizing first inserted(the smallest id)

Tags: mysql, sorting, left-join

Hello  i know my actual question it's look like a bit complicated,

so first i have 
**student**

```
+------------+------- +---------+
| id_student | score_a|score_b  |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 1          | 70     |80       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 2          | 70     |90       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 3          | 80     |70       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 4          | 80     |70       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 5          | 80     |90       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 6          | 60     |70       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 7          | 60     |80       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 8          |40      |70       |
+------------+--------+---------+
```

then **class**

```
+----------+--------------+
| id_class | limit_people |
+----------+--------------+
| 1        | 2            |
+----------+--------------+
| 2        | 2            |
+----------+--------------+
| 3        | 1            |
+----------+--------------+
```

and the last lets say **register**.
on this table student can choose 2 class but they only can be on 1 class ( the inserted first is the priority) when it's sorted using order by sum of 2 scores ( `student.score_a` and `student.score_b`) DESC  with limit based on `class.limit_people` field(is this even possible?), i'll give you a this table but i don't know if this right or not. I hope you can give a better field/column for this

**register**

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| id_register | id_students | id_class |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 1           | 1           | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 2           | 1           | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 3           | 2           | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 4           | 2           | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 5           | 3           | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 6           | 3           | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 7           | 4           | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 8           | 4           | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

and current query that i used is

```
SELECT register.id_register, register.id_students, SUM((student.score_a*50/100)+ (student.score_b*50/100)) as total,register.id_class 
FROM `register` LEFT JOIN `student` ON register.id_students=student.id_student 
GROUP by register.id_register ORDER BY total DESC
```

and this is the result

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| id_register | id_students | total | id_class |
 +-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 3           | 2           | 80    | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 4           | 2           | 80    | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 2           | 1           | 75    | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 5           | 3           | 75    | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 6           | 3           | 75    | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 7           | 4           | 75    | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 8           | 4           | 75    | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 1           | 1           | 75    | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
```

as you can see all students  showed 2 times , how to make it only 1 without summing all `total` that have the same id_students, and how to prioritize to showed the firt inserted id, if there's multiple records with the same `register.id_students` ?

This is the table that i wanted

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| id_register | id_students | total | id_class |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 3           | 2           | 80    | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 1           | 1           | 75    | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 5           | 3           | 75    | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 7           | 4           | 75    | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: It is not even clear what you are seeking help with.  Do you need help with a query, a schema, both?

Comment: I'll add the requested table that i want

Comment: Are you asking for MySQL or SQL Server? Tag only the correct technologies

Comment: mysql , tag edited sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY register.id_students` instead of `GROUP by register.id_register` to get unique values of the `id_students` field. So the query will be kile following:

```
SELECT 
  register.id_register, 
  register.id_students, 
  (student.score_a + student.score_b)*50/100 AS total,
  register.id_class 
FROM 
  `register` 
LEFT JOIN 
  `student` 
ON (register.id_students = student.id_student)
GROUP BY register.id_students 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: already using this, but the total field will be summed multiple times if there's multiple id_students with same value on register table

Comment: @KRISBIANTOROPRABOWO, the `SUM()` is an [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html), don't use it. I have added complete query to my answer.

Comment: thanks dude, it's working don't know if sum is the one of the problems here

Comment: is there a way if let's say one of class reach the max limit based on `class.limit_people` field, can't be the records that contain those id_class will not be showed again
for example :
`class.limit_people = 1` for `id_class = 1` , and in the resulted table there's 2 records that using `id_class=1` , can't it only be showed only once(the students that have the higher `register.total`?

Comment: @KRISBIANTOROPRABOWO, ti is difficult :)